Android force to use light theme color
For a page that adapts to both dark and light modes, there is a specific popup that requires forcing the use of colors defined for the light theme. The color naming for light and dark themes is the same. I’ve researched extensively but couldn’t find any similar issues. How should I implement this functionality correctly? I hope someone can provide the correct approach. I don’t want to define another set of color values because if I need to change the colors later, this part might get overlooked.
I have already tried using ContextThemeWrapper, but it had no effect.
//    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): BottomSheetDialog {
//        // 使用 ContextThemeWrapper force use Light theme
//        val wrappedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme_Light)
//        return BottomSheetDialog(wrappedContext, theme)
//    }

This is style xml
<resources>

    <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_surface3</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle.Light" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>


All you want to do is force the application to be with a light theme regardless of what the user chooses on his/her device?

@tomerpacific The app follows the system settings, but the UI design specifies a bottom popup that should always use the color values from the Light mode, regardless of the current mode. For example, the popup background, text color, and so on.

if you want a specific piece of UI to always use the same design, why make it use a theme color?
